# Comparison negative binomial model and quasi-Poisson

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, model-comparison, quasi-likelihood

I have run negative binomial and quasi-Poisson models based on an hypothesis testing approach. My final models using both methods have different covariates and interactions. It seems that there are no patterns when I plot my residuals in both cases. Thus, I was wondering which test I could use to see which model fits my data better as the quasi-Poisson does not have any likelihood or AIC…

Also, I have a lot of overdispersion which makes me think that the negative binomial would be more appropriate, but I don't know if I can choose my model based on common sense…

Answer (score 10):

I see the quasi-poisson as a technical fix; it allows you to estimate as an additional parameter $\phi$, the dispersion parameter. In the Poisson $\phi = 1$ by definition. If your data are not as or more dispersed than that, the standard errors of the model coefficients are biased. By estimating $\hat{\phi}$ at the same time as estimating the other model coefficients, you can provide a correction to the model standard errors, and hence their test statistics and associated $p$-values. This is just a correction to the model assumptions.

The negative binomial is a more direct model for the overdispersion; that the data generating process is or can be approximated by a negative-binomial.

The quasi-Poisson also introduces a whole pile of practical issues such as it not having a true likelihood hence the whole stack of useful things for model selection, like likelihood ratio test, AIC, etc... (I know there is something called QAIC, but R's `glm()` for example won't give you it).